# Changing the structure of rows and columns in a data frame- R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large database (90,000 * 1500) sorted by child observations - which includes their mom's info. I want to sort the database according to mom's data.

The problem is that each kid only appears once in DB mom bs. It may appear up to 10 times.

In addition, I want the number of rows to be a number of different mothers (approx. 40,000) and a bit of data for each child - between 0-10.

For example, the DB I have and the DB I want to create:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. This question is a bit too involved, to not have a example to go by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution similar to [@Metariat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390986/12158757), but with `base R`, where `ave()` is used

```
df$seq <- with(df,ave(id_num,mom,FUN = seq_along))
dfout <- reshape(df, idvar = "mom", timevar = "seq", direction = "wide")
```

such that

```
> dfout
  mom c.1 id_num.1 age.1  c.2 id_num.2 age.2
1   1  c1        1    12   c3        3     5
2   3  c2        2    15   c5        5    19
4   2  c4        4     8 <NA>       NA    NA
```

**EDIT**:
If you have very big data frame, you can try the divide and conquer policy to see if it works

```
library(plyr)
dfs <- split(df,df$mom)
lst <- lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  x <- within(x,seqnum <- ave(id_num,mom,FUN = seq_along))
  reshape(x, idvar = "mom", timevar = "seqnum", direction = "wide")
}
)
dfout <- rbind.fill(lst)
```

Comment: thanks. I tried to do that, but i got "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 336 Kb"

Comment: @AviyaWeiser maybe you have a big data frame to deal with?

Comment: @AviyaWeiser I am not sure if some package that has this kind of `reshape` function such that bigger data frame can be processed. Otherwise it might be better to write a customized function to do it

Comment: @AviyaWeiser I added another solution trying to process large data frame, you can try it out

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reshape`

```
 library(data.table)
 df = data.frame(
   'c' = c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'),
   'id_num' = seq(1,5),
   'age' = c(12, 15, 5, 8, 19),
   'mom'= c(1,3,1,2,3)
 )
 df
   c id_num age mom
1 c1      1  12   1
2 c2      2  15   3
3 c3      3   5   1
4 c4      4   8   2
5 c5      5  19   3
 df = setDT(df)[order(mom)]
 df[, id_child := seq(.N), mom]

 reshape(df, idvar = "mom", timevar = "id_child", direction = "wide")
   mom c.1 id_num.1 age.1  c.2 id_num.2 age.2
1:   1  c1        1    12   c3        3     5
2:   2  c4        4     8 <NA>       NA    NA
3:   3  c2        2    15   c5        5    19
```

Comment: thanks.
my code: 
data_by_mom = setDT(jps)[order(mid_505)]
data_by_mom[, kid_505 := seq(.N), mid_505]
and i got:
Error in `[.data.table`(data_by_mom, , `:=`(kid_505, seq(.N)), mid_505) : Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)

Comment: you should consider converting your column kid_5055 to numeric before `data_by_mom = setDT(jps)[order(mid_505)] data_by_mom[, kid_505  := as.numeric(kid_505)][, kid_505 := seq(.N), mid_505]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `tidyr` package, with `group_by`.

```
group_by(data, mom)
```

Then each mom contains a list of children. You can then sort the database as follows.

```
arrange(data, id_num, .by_group = TRUE)
```

To filter children between 0 and 10:

```
filter(data, age <= 10)
```